# I cannot post image in mvc

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

I want to create a form that uploads pictures to my directory. Using ajax i want to display the image uploaded in the img tag just below but i cant doit.
My codes:

### Ajax codes:

```
function tempupl()
{
    var file = document.getElementById("image");
    var form = new FormData();
    alert(file.files[0].name);
    form.append("image", file.files[0]);
    pather = "@Url.Action("uploadpi","countries")";
    $.ajax({
        type: "Post",
        url: pather,
        data: form,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data);
            var a = data;
            return a;
        }
    });
}
```

My controller:This is my controller to upload image to folder.I returned   Json objects to my ajax .

```
    public ActionResult uploadpi(HttpPostedFileBase image)
    {
        JsonResult j = new JsonResult();
        if (image != null && image.ContentLength > 0)
        {
            string fullpath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Contents/"), Path.GetFileName(image.FileName));
            if (System.IO.File.Exists(fullpath))
            {
                System.IO.File.Delete(fullpath);
            }
            image.SaveAs(fullpath);
        }
        j.Data = Path.GetFileName(image.FileName)                                     
        return (j);
    }
```

My form:This is my form to upload image and it also has img tag to display image I uploaded but it doesnot work.

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)

<fieldset>
    <legend>pic</legend>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.picpath)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.picpath)
        <input type="file" id="image" name="image"  /><input type="button"                               value="upload" onclick="tempupl()" />
            </div>
<img src="@Url.Content("a")" alt="" id="pic" name="pic"/>
```

I cant insert my filepath on the @url.content in the ajax success function .

Answer (score 0):

I do not think you can post image using only Ajax and common HTML.
If you want to upload file without refreshing the entire page, there are two ways:
[1] using HTML5 with ajax (http://www.sitepoint.com/html5-ajax-file-upload/)
[2] using iframe to simulate ajax upload file (http://www.alfajango.com/blog/ajax-file-uploads-with-the-iframe-method/)

I hope it can help you